# How do I specify the input to a Volterra series including the kernels?

Tags: taylor-expansion

I have a series of dependent and independent variables. I would like to model their relation using a Volterra/Wiener series. How do I specify:

- $h_n$
- $a$, $b$
- Input vector $x_n$
- The kernels for each order
- etc?

Example data:

$$\begin{array}{c|c|c|c|c} 
 & y_1 & y_2 & x_1 & x_2 \\ \hline
\text{1} & 0.523 & 1 & 4 & 1 \\ \hline
\text{2} & 0.702 & 2 & 2 & 1 \\ \hline
\text{3} & 0.500 & 1 & 2 & 2 \\ \hline
\text{4} & 0.722 & 2 & 1 & 2 \\ \hline
\end{array}$$